# Unable to find the Corda CLI, has it been installed?

Tags: corda, corda-flow, corda-dlt

I am trying to run nodes on Corda. I have corda cli (5.0.1) installed, but I am getting the error, 'Unable to find the Corda CLI, has it been installed?' in IntelliJ 2021. Any configuration I am missing?

Corda is initializing well, but when I try to run the virtual nodes, I get the missing cli problem.

Comment: Looks like a path problem to me. IntelliJ expects the Conda CLI installation at another path. Try to figure out the defined path and change it to your current installation path.